# Is there a way to do "template base class" in Python?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, templates

Suppose there are two classes `Base1`, `Base2` that are inherited from a common base class `Base`. And also there is some function `ff` that works with `Base`.

In C++ one can define a template class `Derived` that will inherit either from `Base1` or from `Base2`, create objects of that type and pass them to `ff`:

```
// Given
struct Base1 : Base { };
struct Base2 : Base { };
void ff(const Base& base) { }

// you can do...
template < typename BB >
struct Derived : public BB { /* implement here what is common to both Derived1 and Derived2 */ };
struct Derived1 : public Derived<Base1> { /* implement here what is specific to Derived1 but not Derived2 */ };
struct Derived2 : public Derived<Base2> { /* implement here what is specific to Derived2 but not Derived1 */ };

// ... and live your life in peace with: 
Derived1 d1;
Derived2 d2;
ff(d1);
ff(d2);
```

The question is how can I implement the same architecture in Python3.6?

Comment: I don't think _Multiple Inheritance_ means what you think it means.

Comment: It currently means what I think it means. It might be used in tricks with Python while trying to construct such architecture. But yes, I did not mentioned that tricks as they not quite completely solve my problem, and maybe I should remove it from the tags. Thanks.

Comment: you better ask for what you actually want to achieve by that (in python!). Attempting to directly translate code from one language to another often creates more difficulties that necessary, because solutions for the same problem may be completely different

Comment: Yes it is possible and it is probably simpler that the C++ way because Python naturally allows dynamic typing, duck typing and monkey patching (just google for those names).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote myself a toy library for this to play around with metaclasses. You can get it with `pip install type_templating` [from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/type-templating/0.1.0/).  Derived from [one of its tests](https://github.com/eric-wieser/type_templating/blob/1d1a6990b3567b4244d0fc1844403fe07e4587a9/test/test_type_templating.py#L91-L100).

```
from type_templating import Template, TemplateParameter

class Base: pass
class Base1(Base): pass
class Base2(Base): pass

BB = TemplateParameter('BB')

# Derived is a template taking one argument
class Derived(BB, metaclass=Template[BB]):
    # implement here what is common to both Derived1
    # and Derived2. The template argument is accessible as
    # `self.__args[BB]`
    pass

class Derived1(Derived[Base1]): pass
class Derived2(Derived[Base2]): pass
```

Unlike the builtin `typing.Generic`, this does not erase template argument information, and allows values to be passed as well as types.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is just to show that it is possible in Python, but IMHO it is not really Pythonic because it is just mimicing C++ templates.

```
>>> class Base:
    pass

>>> class Base1(Base):
    pass

>>> class Base2(Base):
    pass

>>> def templated(base):     # a Python decorator to mimic the C++ templating engine
    def outer(clazz):
        class Inner(base):
            _base = base      # a class attribute that will be tested later
        return Inner
    return outer

>>> class Derived:
    pass         # implement what is common to both Derived1 and Derived2

>>> @templated(Base1)
class Derived1:
    pass         # implement what is specific to Derived1

>>> Derived1._base        # to prove that it extends Derived<Base1> (C++ like syntax)
<class '__main__.Base1'>
>>> Derived1.__mro__      # base classes
(<class '__main__.templated.<locals>.outer.<locals>.Inner'>, <class '__main__.Base1'>,
<class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>)
>>>
```

But on any real example, there would certainly be a more simple way...

Comment: You completely discard the contents of `Derived1` here